# AngularJS getting data from controller to directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I am trying do display data retrieved from database in controller to directive. I am using Controller as syntax, but when i try to display my data in directive it is undefined. I am getting right value for name and example variable, but not for items variable.

TaskCtrl.js

```
 app.controller('TasksCtrl', ['$scope', 'TaskService', function ($scope,       TaskService) {
    // initialize function
    this.newTask = true;
    this.name = "My name is Nedim";
    this.example = "Example";

    this.templates = {
        new: "views/task/addTask.html",
        view: "views/task/viewTask.html"
    };

    // load all available tasks
    TaskService.loadAllTasks().then(function (data) {
        this.items = data.tasks;
    });

    $scope.$on('newTaskAdded', function(event, data){
        this.items.concat(data.data);
    });

    return $scope.TasksCtrl = this;

}]);
```

taskList.html

```
<ul class="list-group">
<li ng-repeat="item in taskCtrl.items" class="list-group-item">
    <a ng-click="openItem()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
        <span>{{item.name}}</span>
        <span class="task-description">{{item.description}}</span>
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
<div>{{taskCtrl.name}}</div>
<div>{{taskCtrl.example}}</div>
<div>{{taskCtrl.items}}</div>
```

entityTaskList directive

```
 app.directive('entityTaskList', function(){
 return {
 restrict: 'E',
 templateUrl: 'views/task/taskList.html',
 scope: {
     items: '='
 },
 bindToController: true,
 controller: 'TasksCtrl as taskCtrl',
 link: function(scope, element, attrs){
     console.log("items" + scope.items);
     scope.openItem = function(){
         var ctrl = scope.taskCtrl;
         ctrl.newTask = false;
     };
 }
 };
 });
```

task.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <entity-task-list items="items"></entity-task-list>  
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" ng-controller="TaskDetailCtrl as taskDetailCtrl">
        <!-- form for adding new task -->
        <div ng-show="taskCtrl.newTask" ng-include="taskCtrl.templates.new"></div>
        <!-- container for displaying existing tasks -->
        <div ng-show="!taskCtrl.newTask" ng-include="taskCtrl.templates.view"></div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have forgotten to use the controller name for referencing the variable.

So in your directive you have:

```
controller: 'TasksCtrl as taskCtrl'
```

Meaning this should be:

```
<entity-task-list items="taskCtrl.items">
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be `this`. When you use functions like:

```
TaskService.loadAllTasks().then(function (data) {
    this.items = data.tasks;
});

$scope.$on('newTaskAdded', function(event, data){
    this.items.concat(data.data);
});
```

then `this` in these functions' body refers to the function's scope rather than the controller's scope, so you're setting properties on the wrong `this` object.

To avoid this problem you can do one of the following:

**option 1:**

Use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind). For example:

```
TaskService.loadAllTasks().then(function (data) {
    this.items = data.tasks;
}.bind(this));

$scope.$on('newTaskAdded', function(event, data){
    this.items.concat(data.data);
}.bind(this));
```

**option 2:**

A common practice in Angular controllers is to save `this` in a local variable, and then use that variable instead. Example:

```
app.controller('TasksCtrl', ['$scope', 'TaskService', function ($scope, TaskService) {
  // initialize function
  var vm = this;
  vm.newTask = true;
  vm.name = "My name is Nedim";
  vm.example = "Example";

  vm.templates = {
    new: "views/task/addTask.html",
    view: "views/task/viewTask.html"
  };

  // load all available tasks
  TaskService.loadAllTasks().then(function (data) {
    vm.items = data.tasks;
  });

  $scope.$on('newTaskAdded', function(event, data){
    vm.items.concat(data.data);
  });

  return $scope.TasksCtrl = this;

}]);
```